# How to change height of items in ListBox in powershell?

Tags: winforms, powershell, listbox

I'm trying to set the height of **items** to be equal to the height of `ListBox`. In other words, only one **item** must be visible in `ListBox`. Right now, two items are visible.

[image]

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

# $OwnerDrawVariable = [Windows.Forms.DrawMode]::OwnerDrawVariable
# $OwnerDrawFixed = [Windows.Forms.DrawMode]::OwnerDrawFixed

$form                            = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.ClientSize                 = '400,400'
$form.text                       = "Form"
$form.TopMost                    = $false

$listBox                = New-Object Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.text           = "listBox"
$listBox.width          = 80
$listBox.height         = 30
$listBox.location       = New-Object Drawing.Point(70,10)
# $listBox.IntegralHeight = $false
# $listBox.DrawMode     = $OwnerDrawVariable
$listBox.ItemHeight     = 30

@('1','2','3') | ForEach-Object {[void] $listBox.Items.Add($_)}

$form.controls.AddRange(@($listBox))

[void]$form.ShowDialog()
```

I've tried changing `DrawMode` property as well as `IntegralHeight` to no avail. Any advice?

Comment: Try a value of 17 for `$listBox.height`

Comment: @T-Me, it works, but I'd like to keep the original height

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a [ComboBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?view=netframework-4.8) rather than a [ListBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: @Theo, actually, you're right, it's much better for my needs. However, after playing around with it for a bit, I discovered that it's not easy to change the height of `ComboBox`. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the value name indicates, `[DrawMode]::OwnerDrawFixed` requires the control owner (that's you!) to explicitly draw the items on screen.

You can do so by adding an event handler to the `DrawItem` event property:

```
$listBox.add_DrawItem({
    param(
        [object]$sender,
        [System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs]$eargs
    )

    $eargs.DrawBackground()

    $eargs.Graphics.DrawString($listBox.Items[$eargs.Index].ToString(), $eargs.Font, [System.Drawing.Brushes]::Black, $eargs.Bounds.Left, $eargs.Bounds.Top)
    $eargs.DrawFocusRectangle()
})
```

`$eargs.Font` is inherited from `$listbox.Font`, so modify that if you want the drawn strings to be larger as well:

```
$listBox.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::new($listBox.Font.FontFamily.Name, 18)
```